# Как правильно произносить фамилию Беен (немецкая)?

Tags: гласные

Например Фриц Беен. Следует тянуть "е" или произносить её как двойную?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если речь идет об актере и режиссере Бене Фритце, то, во-первых, стоит писать его имя только так: Бен Фритц — в языке-источнике оно записывается как Ben Fritz. Тогда вопрос отпадает.

Во-вторых, в подобных случаях обычно произносятся обе гласные, ср. Илья Леенсон.